# Calling Objective-C method by clicking text inside UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, uiwebview, uitextview

I query a SQLite db and the query returns some links: I can display them in a `UITextView` or in a `UIWebView`.

What I need to know is: is there a way to bind an action to a link inside a `UIWebView` (or even `UITextView`)? **I don't want to open a webpage, I just want to execute a method of Objective-C** as the link was a button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delegate method

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

and check for `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`, then inspect the `[aRequest URL]` to determine what the link action should be.

Comment: thanks for reply. A further question: should I store the links as HTML links (<a href="...) or they get converted automatically by the UIWebView even leaving them as they are?

Comment: I would probably go with using the URL to store your data; you could use the scheme to identify that it was for private use, etc.  The web view will generate the NSURLRequest from that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible via JavaScript, see this doc: [Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html).